# Location Path as variable in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open excel file Project.xlsx from macro. So I am using this in my macro.

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Project.xlsx")
```

However, the location for Project.xlsx might be random. 
So I am planning to create another workbook called master.xlsx which contain the default location for project.xlsx.
here is my master.xlsx with cell A2 contain the location for Project.xlsx.
[image]

Can anybody help me how to write the code in macro for now? I guess it will be like

```
Workbooks.Open (Master.xlsx!Sheet1!A2 & "Project.xlsx")
```

Comment: It looks like it should be exactly like that. Didn't it work?

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic qualifications to let VBA know exactly where it can find the Master workbook.

This procedure assumes that the Master.xlsx workbook isn't open. And you'll have to specify the path to it.

```
Sub tmp()
    Dim master_wb As Workbook, project_wb As Workbook

    Set master_wb = Workbooks.Open(path_to_your_master_workbook & "\Master.xlsx")

    Set project_wb = Workbooks.Open( _
        master_wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "Project.xlsx")

    master_wb.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax is `'[WorkbookName]WorksheetName'!CellAddress`.

In your case, `Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Range("'[Master.xlsx]Sheet1'!A2").Value & "Project.xlsx")`.

But I wonder where do you store the macro? As none indicated a Macro-Enabled Excel file.

Comment: macro is in another excel file. so it is in "raspi.xlsm".
I want to open project.xlsx from macro in raspi.xlsm. But the location of project.xlsx is in master.xlsx

Comment: I tried your method and this error come: error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global'

Comment: @RaspiSurya Sorry I put the `'` at the wrong place.